# How to give a role create and delete permissions to a node in Kentico API?

Tags: c#, kentico, kentico-api

I'm using the following example to update role permission on a tree node via Kentico API:

https://docs.kentico.com/api11/content-management/page-security#Pagesecurity-Settingpagepermissionsforarole

Not able to figure out how to assign multiple permissions, for instance Allow Create and Allow Delete. Any example greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum all values that you get from permission flag method into allowed and save it:

```
    if (role != null)
    {
        int allowed = DocumentSecurityHelper.GetNodePermissionFlags(NodePermissionsEnum.Create);
        allowed += DocumentSecurityHelper.GetNodePermissionFlags(NodePermissionsEnum.Delete);
        // Prepares a value indicating that no page permissions are denied
        int denied = 0;

        AclItemInfoProvider.SetRolePermissions(page, allowed, denied, role);
    }
```